# stb _mm_slli_si128 the last argument must be an 8 bit immediate in code that does not even compile

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I recently switched to linux, And In one of my projects I have been using stb for loading textures. However when I include the stb header file I get an error message that looks like this.

```
In function ‘__m128i _mm_slli_si128(__m128i, int)’,
    inlined from ‘stbi_uc* stbi__resample_row_hv_2_simd(stbi_uc*, stbi_uc*, stbi_uc*, int, int)’ at lib/stb/stb/stb_image.h:3359:32:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.1/include/emmintrin.h:1229:10: error: the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate
 1229 |   return (__m128i)__builtin_ia32_pslldqi128 (__A, __N * 8);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function ‘__m128i _mm_srli_si128(__m128i, int)’,
    inlined from ‘stbi_uc* stbi__resample_row_hv_2_simd(stbi_uc*, stbi_uc*, stbi_uc*, int, int)’ at lib/stb/stb/stb_image.h:3360:32:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.1/include/emmintrin.h:1223:10: error: the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate
 1223 |   return (__m128i)__builtin_ia32_psrldqi128 (__A, __N * 8);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I looked at it and for some weird reason, the code that throws this issue, is inside an #ifdef __OPTIMIZE __ block and does not even compile. Like literally, in Visual studio Code the code at lines 1223 and 1229 is greyed out because __OPTIMIZE __ is not defined (I am running in Debug).

The actual code that runs `_mm_slli_si128` is:

```
__m128i prv0 = _mm_slli_si128(curr, 2);
__m128i nxt0 = _mm_srli_si128(curr, 2);
```

I am running on Manjaro KDE and using GCC 12.2.1 20230201. I know the issue that the second parameter must be something that the compiler knows at compile time, but it is, and the whole thing that causes an error should not even compile and I just do not know what to do.

Comment: Is there any chance you are using the `-include <file>` flag? For some reason, even with an empty file, the `-include <file>` flag ends up defining __OPTIMIZE__. Seems like a GCC bug?

Comment: @RussellGreene I do not remember to be honest, I know I fixed it somehow but I do not remember how. But thanks a lot for responding.

Comment: I have solved this issue, however I do not remember how as it was 4 months ago.